# Marie-Curie individual felowship - current organization

Tags: funding

is there any problem if I don't work at an European University as a Postdoctoral fellow (just back from the USA) at the time that I submit the Marie-Curie fellowship (2-3 months without job)?

thank you

Answer (score 2):

It's clearly allowed and even encouraged:

> Individual Fellowships provide opportunities to researchers of any
>   nationality to acquire and transfer  new  knowledge  and  to  work  on
>   research  and  innovation  in  Europe  (EU  Member States  and 
>   Horizon  2020  Associated  Countries)  and  beyond.  The  scheme 
>   particularly supports  the  return  and  (re)integration  of  European
>   researchers  from  outside  Europe  and those who have previously
>   worked here, as well as researchers displaced by conflict outside the 
>   EU  and  Horizon  2020  Associated Countries.  It  also  promotes  the
>   career  restart  of individual researchers who show great potential

http://ec.europa.eu/research/participants/data/ref/h2020/wp/2018-2020/main/h2020-wp1820-msca_en.pdf (p. 13)