# How to find host institution - Marie-Curie individual fellowship

Tags: funding, eu, marie-curie

How to find the list of host institution for Marie-Curie individual fellowship? Does it mean that the host institution must have already received or get approved for Marie-Curie individual fellowship?

[Another post on host institution MSCA IF](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/132895/marie-curie-individual-felowship-current-organization)

Comment: If anyone has it, it would be the Marie Curie site... but this answer may help : https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/132898/72855

Comment: @SolarMike could you please provide the link? I am getting messed with the huge amount of information in the site. Moreover, candidate must always choose the host institution mentioned in the site?

Comment: See the linked document in that answer, I’m not copying that link just for the sake of repeating it here...

Comment: @SolarMike  thank you, understand.

Comment: @scaaahu I read the above link before I post. I have a distinct question. For the ease of reading, I add the above link.

Comment: Dup vote retracted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to find the list of host institution for Marie-Curie individual fellowship?

There's no list, any legal entity in the EU or in a partner country is eligible: http://ec.europa.eu/research/participants/data/ref/h2020/wp/2018-2020/main/h2020-wp1820-msca_en.pdf p.76

As far as I know it's more common to apply with a university or a research institution, but companies can be host institutions as well.

> Does it mean that the host institution must have already received or get approved for Marie-Curie individual fellowship?

No, but it's possible that the institution would have to be registered on the EU portal (this is how it works for H2020 proposals, I'm not sure about Marie Curie actions).

The eligibiity conditions are rather easy to satisfy, but in order to have any chance of success it's very important to understand that the selection relies very strongly on the excellence of the research proposal **in collaboration with the host institution**. This means that before applying, any serious candidate must contact a potential PI and design a detailed research plan with them. I think it's crucial to understand what the EU expects to achieve through these grants in order to write a decent application, because they are not just giving away funding to kind junior researchers :)

Some EU institutions have a specialized office to help applicants write good applications. If the target host institution does it's a really good idea to contact them and ask them for advice, it can drastically increases your chances.

(and yes, the EU website is a monster, but given time one can find really useful information in there)

---

[Edit] additional sources of information (among many)

- https://www.mariecuriealumni.eu/magazine/news/want-become-marie-sk%C5%82odowska-curie-fellow-individual-fellowships-if-spotlight
- National Contact Points (NCP): https://ec.europa.eu/info/funding-tenders/opportunities/portal/screen/support/ncp (select target country and Marie Curie Actions)

Comment: Now I am getting some clues. Unless one who already received/applied the fellowship or guided someone tell the fresh applicant, it is impossible to find where and how to apply.

Comment: @user199 added some links  in the answer, hope it helps. Good luck!

Comment: No words to say thank you. I’m wondering, in general, MSCA accepts only one proposal per applicant or multiple proposals from an applicant can be submitted?

Comment: pdf linked above p 13: "Only one proposal per individual researcher per call will be evaluated." This means only one application but you can re-apply at the next call (one year later I guess)

Comment: I got this, thank you a lot.