# Marie Curie IF, can secondments be hosted by my PhD institution?

Tags: funding, marie-curie

I would like to include an official secondment in my Marie Curie fellowship to be carried out at the Institution where I got my PhD (a couple of years ago).

I understand that Marie Curie is about mobility and this might not be seen favorably, but if well justified can it be included?

Thank you for any advice and best wishes

Comment: I don't understand why people are voting to close this question as off-topic, can somebody explain?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand from [the official documentation](https://ec.europa.eu/research/participants/data/ref/h2020/wp/2018-2020/main/h2020-wp1820-msca_en.pdf), the secondment stage is meant to increase the impact of the fellowship in the host institution. From a cursory reading I don't see any reason why it couldn't take place in the PhD institution, as long as there is a solid motivation for it.

As I mentioned in [another question about MSC](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/132951/93566):

> Some EU institutions have a specialized office to help applicants write good applications. If the target host institution does it's a really good idea to contact them and ask them for advice, it can drastically increase your chances.

Comment: Unfortunately my institution does not have such an office...